# Notation for the closed set $[a,b]$ and set $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, notation

In one dimensional space, $(a,b)$ and $[a,b]$ are common.

Now consider $a,b\in\mathbb R^2$,

Define $[a,b]$ be the segment $\overline{ab}$. Let $(a,b)$ be the segment without the endpoints.

Are these notations standard? Has these notations be used before?

One thing worried me is that $(a,b)$ usually means an open set and in my definition $(a,b)$ is not open. So this notation could be informal and sloppy. $[a,b]$ seems to be a closed set, though.

Comment: As a matter of exposition, I wouldn't just drop that notation down and expect people to understand it by default.  But it's not that hard to explain what you're doing.

Comment: You have already the notation $\overline{ab}$. Any reason to introduce this new notation?

Comment: @BrianTung Are there any standard notation for these types of objects?

Comment: @ArcticChar: Presumably OP wants to distinguish between the interval with its endpoints and without.

Comment: These notations are quite common (in convexity theory, for example). They look better if you use bold font for the vectors. If you are writing a paper, it would be a good idea to say what you mean when you first use the notations.

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes $[a,b]=\overline{ab}$, but what about $(a,b)$? If I am going to use both, then I think it is better to unify the notation style.

Comment: @RobArthan It is good to know that these notations are common; much appreciate for your knowledge. Are there any book or paper that I can use as the reference for these notations so I can learn how did professional mathematicians write them down?

Comment: Regarding your final concern, $(\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b})$ isn't an open subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$, but it is an [open line segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment). I can't give you a canonical reference for the interval style notation, but is very common in convexity theory and other subjects. With most mathematical audiences, you should  just need a parenthetic remark to explain your choice of notation.

Comment: @RobArthan  Many thanks for your inputs! I love mathematics because in theory we can define any notation as we want. However, after my work becomes longer and longer I find out that few people will actually read my work if my notation is not familiar to them. So I am always trying to find the most common notations. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on who’s using them, but it is a typical notation that is frequently found in topics where connecting lines are important, such as convex analysis. But then there is no real mathematical standard notation for these things, as the use depends on how often one needs such things. In linear algebra $[a,b]$ could also mean the vector space created by $a$ and $b$ for examble.

Comment: Many thanks for your knowledge. May I ask if $(a,b)$ is commonly used? In this case $(a,b)$ is no longer an open set so I am in concern.

Comment: @HighGPA I don’t think so. For one thing $(a,b)$ willl usually be read as a pair, so it might be confusing. Also in most cases this kind of notation is used I think the endpoints do not really matter.